# Don't shoot them! it will just make them mad

Tags: creature-design

"Look out that's a Bundavark.  No don't shoot at it!  Sure you'll blow some big holes in it, but it won't do any good, it will just make it mad."

Bullets are a really ineffective way to attack Bundavarks and its not because the Bundavark are heavily armored.  Why are bullets ineffective?

The best answers will have the creature that is the most unaffected by bullet holes with the smallest amount of hand waving.

Comment: Since we don't know what a bundvark is or why we *would* shoot it or how it would retaliate after being shot, the answers to this question can only be someone's opinions.

Comment: I went with unclear because simply asking why at the end of the sentence could be taken a bunch of different ways.

Comment: To my understanding the question is asking for answers to produce a creature that is as unaffected by bullets as is possible. While this would certainly be a fit, some constraints would likely improve reception of the question.

Comment: I imagined a giant slime that just doesn't care that it gets shot.

Comment: I could see it asking " why is it a bad idea to attack them will bullets" because they are cute and cuddly and crap rainbow sherbet.

Comment: I agree with Green that any answer on here would only be an opinion on a possible creature. (Not to mention the question took me a few re-reads to understand.)

Comment: Tired to clarify Looking for a creature that is unaffected by bullets in a way other then lots of armor.  Are there other confusions / reasons for down votes

Comment: How do you spell it? You use 3 different spelling.

Comment: Bears.  Particularly grizzly bears, but your ordinary black bear is not that much bothered by fairly small caliber bullets.

Answer (score 5):

Make the Bundvark a colony type creature. Think FireAnts, Man o' War, Killer Bees.

You shoot it and it causes damage, but it pissed off the rest of the swarm/smart colony.

Alternatively make the Bundvark have multiple redundant organs or extreme regeneration.

Comment: Yah!  Man-O-War Bundvarks!

Comment: Yes, agreed with this one. Similar to Terminator v 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

A bundvark is an ethereal creature so blowing holes in it does actually nothing at all except annoy it when it has to reconstitute itself.

A bundvark has ridiculous regenerative capabilities so any holes that are blown in it heal as quickly as they are made. But this has a metabolic cost and makes the bundvark HUNGRY... and boy do YOU look tasty!

Answer (score 1):

Bundvarks are stupid and viscious, and highly irritable. Their regenerative powers are legendary. Inciting someone to shoot a Bundvark is now a class E felony across NonNivean Known Space, due to their aggrieved rampaging.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a hunter, but as far as I know, all five African big games (elephant, rhino, buffalo and what not – here is the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_five_game)) are like this. A different issue is that the idea of hunting rare animals might be offensive to the modern audience – right so!

Answer (score 0):

Bundvarks are actually a swarm of nanite disassemblers.  Bullets go right through and then as they travel on behind the creature, the few nanites which were actually hit by the bullet, consume it and thus start a new Bundvark swarm colony.

*We had one Bundvark to deal with, but then Jerry shot it so now we have two.*